# Magento 2 : Flush static files cache delete my files in pub folder

Tags: magento2, cache, less-css

Whenever I click the additional cache management buttons in admin panel , it deletes the files in pub folder.

I don't know what is the reason for this.

Anyone know about this?

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Additional Cache Management System have three buttons, which are given below.

> **Flush Catalog Images Cache:**  Pregenerated product images files
>
> **Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache:**  Themes JavaScript and CSS files combined
>   to one file
>
> **Flush Static Files Cache:**  Preprocessed view files and static files

Now if you click on the last button, it will indeed erase all of your static files. Static files are stored in `pub\static\` directory.

So the answer to your question is, it erases the `pub\static` folder because it is what it's purpose !!!

Sorry, in case you intend anything other.

Comment: Please accept the answer in case it helped you or else post your own answer and then accept it later.

Comment: and i have a doubt.  the content in the pub static folder regenerted  every time

Comment: Yes, if you are in develop mode. When you click on that button, it will erase all static files. When you access any page in browser again, then if you are in development mode, it will generate static files for you.