# pub/static folder did not regenerate while deploy

Tags: magento2, css, cache

Whenever I clicked flush static files cache in admin panel it deletes files in pub folder, but it did not regenerate while deployment.

I don't know what is the reason for this.

Anybody who knows. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following command to generate static files after the deployment.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**Disclaimer : This is not related to the answer.**

I can see a similar question that [you have asked few minutes before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194588/magento-2-flush-static-files-cache-delete-my-files-in-pub-folder). I think you should go through [Magento official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com) in details. This will give you better insights about Magento 2. There is always a learning curve for every developer and let's face it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem is, lacking the folder permissions. 
After flushing the cache, please give write permission to your pub/static and var folders.

If you are using Linux, you can try something like

```
chmod -R 777 pub/static/*
chmod -R 777 var/*
```

After executing the above commands, run the static content deploy command.